# Capturing a div using phantomjs on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I am attempting to capture a div element using `phantomjs` and below code is working great when opening google, but when i tried to open a site from my localhost i get an error below.

> TypeError: null is not an object
>   (evaluating'document.querySelector('#capture').getBoundingClientRect')

My HTML (mysite.php)

```
<div id="capture">
   --content here--
</div>
```

My current code

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://localhost/mysite.php', function() {
  // being the actual size of the headless browser
  page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };

  var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector('#capture').getBoundingClientRect();
  });

  page.clipRect = {
    top:    clipRect.top,
    left:   clipRect.left,
    width:  clipRect.width,
    height: clipRect.height
  };

  page.render('cature.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

### Edit

Ok so after some simulation i figured out that its not reading a `.php` file, when i tried to capture a div from a `.html` file it works.

Any suggestions of a work around with this?

Comment: Maybe your server does not have PHP interpreter?

Comment: @Vaviloff yes i have a PHP interpreter on my server.